# Shouldn't skip.slice=1 still generate a css file in Sencha CMD 6.1.176

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, sencha-command

I think using `skip.slice=1` when running

> sencha app build

should still generate a .css file on the build/production folder but that  is not the case with CMD 6.1.1.76

Am I missing something ?

I want to skip slicing images as I won't be supporting old browsers but obviously I still want to generate the proper css file.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it on a clean workspace and it generates CSS in a production build. Have you installed the Compass extension for Sencha Cmd? I've had some problems when I left this deselected on installation.

Comment: Yes, I did install the extension. For me when setting skip.slice=1 it does generate a css file but it's completely empty and my understanding is that slice-images task only creates images for old browsers so it should still build the css but that's not the case for me.